# Fluentbit Grep filter is not sending logs to output

Tags: fluent-bit

I'm testing fluentbit grep filter and sending some nginx logs to my output, but while combining two separate events and writing regex togerther in FILTER its not sending output. But while keeping only single Regex condition its working as expected.

[FILTER]
Name grep
Match *
Regex log SSL\handshaking
Regex log error

Can anyone help me to understand why multiple Regex is not sending output while single regex sending as expected ?

Version used: 2.0.11

Tried with Regex message error & Regex message SSL\handshaking -> No output
Tried with Regex error & Regex SSL\handshaking -> Getting fluentbit failed after restarting the service.

https://github.com/fluent/fluent-bit/issues/7152